# Making editable table using flask and csv file as DB

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am building a flask web application with python and Javascript. So I am using csv file as a DB as this application is very lightweight(Only one user).

In a particular page I am trying to create a completely editable form. What I mean is that the table rows itself is editable and deletable at any place(not in the way were we move to another page where form values are patched to a form field) and when I click submit it should update in DB(csv file)

Image of what I am imagining
[image: Tablepic]

Is that possible using my current setup?
If possible any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

try page like this

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader

@app.route("/home")
def home():        
    values_list=[]
    with open("file.csv", 'r') as f:  #file.csv is name of the csv file
        dict_reader = DictReader(f)
        values_list = list(dict_reader)
    return render_template('home.html', values=values_list)
```